# On the integral: $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \ln(1+\tan(x)) dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

This semester, I take a compulsory subject in advanced calculus. One of beautiful topic is integration. However, I am not sure enough that my solution (step) are correct.

$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \ln(1+\tan(x)) dx$$
We are going to use this 2 properties.
First,
$$\int_{0}^{a} f(x) dx = \int_{0}^{a} f(a-x) dx.$$
Second,
$$1+ \tan\left (\frac{\pi}{4}-x\right) = \frac{2}{1+\tan(x)}.$$
We obtain
$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \ln(1+\tan(x)) dx = \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \ln(2) dx - \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \ln(1+\tan(x)) dx = \frac{\pi}{8}\ln(2).$$

**My Question**
I am going to do this integration:
$$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln(x+1)}{x^2+1} dx.$$
By substituting $x = \tan(\alpha)$, we obtain
$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \ln(1+\tan(\alpha)) d\alpha = \frac{\pi}{8}\ln(2).$$

Are my step correct? I am doubt, just by substituting, and then we get the answer.

Comment: Typo in the last equation: $$ \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \ln(1+\tan(\alpha)) d \color{red}{\alpha} = \frac{\pi}{8}\ln(2). $$

Comment: I'm not sure you wrote out every step, but it looks good.

Comment: For the direct calculation of the initial integral see:                                                                 http://recreatiimatematice.ro/arhiva/articole/RM12011DICU.pdf